# Bootstrap collapsable navbar not working

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't see any difference between my code and the bootstrap example. When you change the page to mobile view the menu switches to a collapsible but clicking the navbar icon doesn't do anything.

```
<div class='main-nav'>
    <div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            </button>
            <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]="['/home']">VetTech</a>
        </div>
        <div class='clearfix'></div>
        <div class='navbar-collapse collapse' id="myNavbar">
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav side-nav'>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/home']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                      <a [routerLink]="['/selectclasses']">
                          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> Class Selection
                      </a>
                </li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                  <a [routerLink]="['/credit']">
                      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag'></span> Credit
                  </a>
              </li>
                <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                    <a [routerLink]="['/affiliates']">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'></span> Affiliates
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li *ngIf="!auth.isAuthenticated()"[routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <a (click)="auth.login()">
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span> Signup / Login
                    </a>
                </li>
              <li *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated()" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
                <a [routerLink]="['/user']">
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Profile
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uh, it works fine? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m0ojexo/)

Comment: hmm it doesn't work in my project I'll upload the CSS perhaps that is to blame.

Comment: maybe you missed incuding, `bootstrap.min.css`, try also including `JQuery` library above `bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: I've included both using NPM and declaring bootstrap.min.css globally in the angular-cli.json style array.

Comment: @ZacharySchwatz your dropdown doest work is that waht you mean to say , does it always dosnt work or only when switching to mobile ?

Comment: It is only a dropdown when switched to mobile. The static menu works fine

Comment: @ZacharySchwatz can you try to replicate the issue in JSFIddle, is that even possible, dont know much of npm. Also any errors in the console(F12)?

Comment: No, no console errors. It seems to work in JSFiddle... very frustrating.

Comment: @Zachary if you can remove the libraries on my one except the ones for bootstrap and jQuery then check if it works....I think if you remove angular library itll work

Comment: Ok unfortunately that wouldn't really be a solution since obviously I need to include the angular library in my project.